# Android - Keep bunch of activities in each task

Tags: android, android-activity

I have few activities.For example A,B,C,D,E,F.
My Home screen is activity A.Now I start Activity B from that and C from Activity B.

- **So now my stack is A->B->C.**

  Now if I press back I should be able to navigate in reverse Order.
  But If I start Activity D from C.
- **I want my stack to be A->D as I want to kill B and C.**

**My expectations is A is my Home screen which should be always there.B and C on having one task and D,E,F having other task.**

**There is one more catch - I can even start activity D->E->F from A and B from F. In that case when I start B from F, *D,E,F* should be removed from stack**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, depending on your application requireents. You should look at using `startActivityForResult()` in order to start one (or more) activities which can then return a result to the `Activity` that launched it. This may be a good solution for you.

The other alternative is to use your `ActivityA` as a kind of "dispatcher. In this case, when `C` wants to launch `D` but also clear the task stack back to `A` first, you can do something like this in `C`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("launchActivity", "ActivityD");
```

Using the flags `CLEAR_TOP` and `SINGLE_TOP` will cause all activities on top of the existing instance of `ActivityA` to be finished and cause the `Intent` to be routed to `onNewIntent()` of the existing instance of `ActivityA`.

Now, in `ActivityA`, override `onNewIntent()` with something like this:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("launchActivity)) {
    if (intent.getExtra("launchActivity").equals("ActivityD")) {
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    } else ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this already.It is working, but it some minor lag in transaction.Actually I have 4 bunch of activities.Thanks,it is the solution, but Is there any other way ?

Comment: I've don't know what would cause a lag, unless your `Activity` is doing too much work on the main thread. You might add some logging to figure out where the lag is coming from. I've given you 2 suggestions for how to accomplish your goals. Without a lot more details I can't suggest anything else.

Comment: I will log that and check.I would like to mention, I have tried second option.